# when does system call the getview function of adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I want to know when the getView function will be called, case I want to refresh the listview, and don't know how to do. something like, there are 7 items shown in a listView , and now , I want to change it to 7 other date and images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need scroll view programmatically, you can use [smoothScrollToPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29) but it supported only in API 8 and higher.

Comment: thx for your  answer,I do use the method smoothscrollToPosition , but the result is that , it do shown more new items , but only 3 more , and that although the images changed. can not get more , and I can  modefiy the backgroud of the item, cause I don't know how to get the item view , will the getChildAt(position)  be helpful? it will show me nullpointer exception...thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

to refresh the listview call

```
Adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged()
```

**EDIT**

generally listview's list item will have same height if you can calculate the height and call

```
ListView.scrollBy(x, y);
```

even simple you can call

```
ListView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

if you know the position

the listview should render the new items you added in the adapter(provided you call the notifydatasetchanged())

Comment: thx for so quick answer, but there comes the problem that, NotifyDataSetChanged() is useful when the data in adapter is changed? But in my case, the data in adapter will not change, I put 50 items in  it , and listview can only display 10 items , now I want to show the next 10 items, how can I do? thx again.

Comment: smoothScrollToPosition(position) likely to add three more items..I don't konw why , it make me feel that it display only the views It create at first..

Comment: I think that, there is no changes in the adapterdataset, cause i have already add all data in it , but listView can only show 10 items of the datas , and I want t show the next 10 items , will the notifydatasetchanged() helpful? I have tried but in vain.